# Entries for Subprograms in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

i have two functions in my code :

```
 function derivative(error, previous_error, dt :in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector is
  variable derivative_val: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  begin
      derivative_val := div(sub(error,previous_error),dt);
      return derivative_val;
  end derivative;


function mul(num1,num2 : in std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0)) return std_logic_vector is
    variable v_TEST_VARIABLE1 : integer;
    variable v_TEST_VARIABLE2 : integer;
    variable n_times: integer:=1;
    variable product: integer:=0;
    begin 
       v_TEST_VARIABLE1 := to_integer(unsigned(num1)) ; 
       v_TEST_VARIABLE2 := to_integer(unsigned(num2)) ;
      for n_times in 1 to v_TEST_VARIABLE2 loop
        product:=product + v_TEST_VARIABLE1;
      end loop;
    return std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(product,16));
  end mul;
```

In the later half I am trying to assign a variable.

```
 variable derivative_term: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := x"0000";
  derivative_term := mul(mul(Kp,Td), derivative(error, previous_error,dt));
```

On compilation, I am getting :

```
No feasible entries for subprogram "mul".
```

Is there any other way to use it?
thanks in advance.

Comment: No it has two, mul(Kp,Td) and derivative(error, previous_error,dt)

Comment: please pick only one SE site for your question.  *(This is a duplicate of  [Entries for Subprograms of VHDL](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116050/entries-for-subprograms-in-vhdl) on EE.SE.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mul` function takes arguments `num*` with type `std_logic_vector(7 downto
0)` thus length 8, and returns result with type `std_logic_vector` of length
16.

So when calling `mul(mul(...), ...)` the outer `mul` gets first argument with
length 16 of type `std_logic_vector`, which does not match the required
argument length for the function.

Instead of writing you own multiplication function, you could use the `"*"` from
`ieee.numeric_std`, which can be used as:

```
slv_16_0 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(slv_8_0) * unsigned(slv_8_1));
```

It also handles unknown values, like `'X'`, and resulting length is sum of
length for the two arguments.

Comment: As you explained, if slv_8_0 is of length 16 and slv_8_1 is of length 8 and i am using function which takes length 8 and 8, is there anyway to resize slv_8_0, considering there is no significant loss?

Comment: If you want to resize a 16 bit `std_logic_vector` to a 8 bit `std_logic_vector`, then you **will** loose some bits.  Truncation of MSBs can in this case be done with `slv_8_1 <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(slv_16_0), 8));`

Comment: This is what I did : variable integration1: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) :=x"0000";variable v2 : std_logic_vector( 15 downto 0);
       variable v3 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);                                                 v2 :=std_logic_vector((unsigned(Kp)*unsigned(integration1)));
        v3 := std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(v2)),8);  I got " Type conversion (to std_logic_vector) can not have aggregate operand." in the assignment statement of v3.

Comment: The `resize` function takes two arguments, but the `,8` is given after end `)` or resize, thus `,8` goes with argument to `std_logic_vector`, thus the error.  You may also want to check length for Kp * integration1, since it is probably too long for v2.